# Change URL in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a login form like this in URL `http://localhost:8080/myproject/login` :

```
<form:form method="POST"  modelAttribute="auth" action="welcome" id="formlogin">
[...]
</form:form>
```

and a controller like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/welcome")
public String welcome([...]) {

    [...]

    if(logins.size() != 1) { 
        return "login"; 
    }

    [...]

    return "welcome";
}
```

the problem is when the login is incorrect i got this URL `http://localhost:8080/myproject/welcome` but i want to get `http://localhost:8080/myproject/login` and get `welcome` just in case the login is correct.

**1st UPDATE**

In my case the best way to use

```
return "redirect:/login"
```

but before i have to add a attribute like this

```
model.put("errorlogin", true);
```

To handle this

```
<c:if test="${ errorlogin == true }">
<label class="loginerror">Login Error</label>
</c:if>
```

But the error message doesn't display and instead i got this URL

```
http://localhost:8080/pagesjaunes/login?errorlogin=true
```

I set a Attribute and I get a Parameter.

**2nd UPDATE**

i fixed the problem with this :

```
<c:if test="${ param.errorlogin == true }">
<label class="loginerror">Login Error</label>
</c:if>
```

Comment: Look into POST-REDIRECT-GET.

Comment: Did you debug to make sure it actually hits `return "login"` part?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your form should thus have `login` as its action, and the method implementing this action should redirect to welcome if the login is successful.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = ResquestMethod.POST)
public String handleLogin([...]) {
    ...
    if (successful) {
        return "redirect:/welcome"
    }
}
```

Comment: i my case the best is this `return "redirect:/login"` but before i have to add a attribute like this `model.put("errorlogin", true);` to handle this `<c:if test="${ errorlogin == true }"><label class="loginerror">Login Error</label></c:if>` but the error message dosen't display and instead i got this URL `http://localhost:8080/pagesjaunes/login?errorlogin=true`